# vb.net how to show progress in a do while loop?

Tags: vb.net, file, copy

I am making an application that involves appending a large number of files to the end of one single file... i am using the filestream class with a buffer to avoid loading the entire files into memory, however, i want to show the progress of each individual file as they are copied, and the name of the current file... this is easy enough, however, doing so inside the foreach loop seams to decrease the preformance dramatically if each file is very small.

here is the code:

```
  Public Function StreamAppendFileToFile(ByVal f1 As String, ByVal f2 As String)
        Dim bytesRead As Integer
        Dim nn As New FileInfo(f1)
        CurrentFsize = nn.Length

        Dim buffer(40096) As Byte
        Using inFile As New System.IO.FileStream(f1, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
            Using outFile As New System.IO.FileStream(f2, IO.FileMode.Append, IO.FileAccess.Write)
                Do
                    bytesRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, 40096)
                    outFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    Application.DoEvents()
                Loop While bytesRead > 0
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
```

if i put something like this the execution time **doubles**:

```
Public Function StreamAppendFileToFile(ByVal f1 As String, ByVal f2 As String)
        Dim bytesRead As Integer
        Dim nn As New FileInfo(f1)
        CurrentFsize = nn.Length

        Dim buffer(40096) As Byte
        Using inFile As New System.IO.FileStream(f1, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
            Using outFile As New System.IO.FileStream(f2, IO.FileMode.Append, IO.FileAccess.Write)
                Do
                    bytesRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, 40096)
                    **Progressbar1.value = Math.Round((bytesRead / CurrentFsize) * 100)**
                    **Application.Doevents()**
                    outFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    Application.DoEvents()
                Loop While bytesRead > 0
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
```

is there a better/faster/more efficiant way of doing this both in terms of stream-appending one file to the other and showing the progress?  thanks..

Comment: There shouldn't be any need for two `Application.DoEvents` inside the loop.  Try it with just one.

Comment: In addition to placing the operation into another thread, how about using a Timer and only updating progress ONCE per second for instance?

Comment: The implicit casting that VB does also slows it down a bit, I believe.  When you do Math.Round((32-bit Integer / 64-bit Integer) * 32-bit Integer) you actually end up with a Decimal or a double-precision float.  So you are probably doing a lot of boxing and unboxing there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the operation takes a lot of time, I suggest to move the operation to another thread. You can use for example the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to do this (and use the events `DoWork` to perform the action and `ProgressChanged` event to report the progress to the UI).

Code example:

First make sure you have a `BackgroundWorker` and it is set to report progress (by setting the property `WorkerReportsProgress` to `True`)

```
' This class is used to pass the information to the BackgroundWorker DoWork event
Private Class IOFilesInfo
    Public Property InFile As String
    Public Property OutFile As String
End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Start the BackgroundWorker if it isn't started yet
    If Not BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
        Dim filesInfo As New IOFilesInfo() With {.InFile = "in.txt", .OutFile = "out.txt"}
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(filesInfo)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    Dim filesInfo As IOFilesInfo = DirectCast(e.Argument, IOFilesInfo)

    ' Get the file info for the input file (the filesize)
    Dim inFileFileInfo As New FileInfo(filesInfo.InFile)
    Dim inFileFileSize As Long = inFileFileInfo.Length

    ' Keep the progress, total amount of bytes read => you could also keep the progress percentage
    Dim totalBytesRead As Integer = 0

    Dim bytesRead As Integer
    Dim buffer(10) As Byte
    Using inFile As New System.IO.FileStream(filesInfo.InFile, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
        Using outFile As New System.IO.FileStream(filesInfo.OutFile, IO.FileMode.Append, IO.FileAccess.Write)
            Do
                bytesRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, 10)
                outFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)

                ' Add the bytesRead to the total and report the progress as a percentage
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead
                worker.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32(totalBytesRead \ inFileFileSize) * 100)
            Loop While bytesRead > 0
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub
```

Comment: Using a background worker is a little harder to do (creating a seperate thread to do the work) but its the best way to "show progress"

Comment: The threading is (mainly) being handled by the BackgroundWorker, so you don't have to worry too much about it :). But indeed, depending on how long the operation takes, it might be overkill to create a separate thread for it (but as what I understand from the topic starter, he has big files).

Comment: Great! I put the progress updating code in a timer and it increased preformance greatly, however, would the preformance be even better in a background worker that updates in the loop?  or should i combine both background worker and timer?

Comment: You just need the background worker. Why would you need the timer? The background worker does it work on a separate thread. Using ReportProgress, you can give the progress status to the UI thread so you can handle the "update of progress" there. Obviously you could make this more performing by keeping a "totalProgressPercentage" rather than the "totalBytesRead" and only report the progress every 1% or even every 5%. So your UI thread doesn't get bombarded with progress reports (wrap the `worker.ReportProgress` in an IF statement).

Comment: I suppose i need the timer so i do not need to give the progress for each loop in the while loop, if i accumulate the progress in a global variable and update to the ui only once per second using a timer, would that not make it faster as it releavs strain on the loop?

Comment: You don't need a timer if you only want to update the progress bar occasionally, put your logic in the `BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged`  event handler.

Comment: @DanielVallandTorgrimsen Please keep in mind that you are in a different thread. Don't use a global variable that you access in different threads, like you are/were planning. It is bound to give errors. Use the "ProgressChanged" event as I displayed and explained, it is there for this exact purpose! If you want to optimise the amount that this event is risen, please read my previous comment! I explained it there.

Comment: Great! thank you, what if i needed to process multiple files in an array? like from an openfiledialog (Multiple inn files appended to the out file)...

Comment: Then you edit the code a little so it accepts an array of "in files". I leave that to you (I am not a code factory that codes everything for you).

Comment: @DanielVallandTorgrimsen If this answer was helpful / answered your question, please mark it as answer to your question :).